# Как заставить работать clip-path в Firefox

Tags: html, css, svg

Здравствуйте как заставить работать clip-path в Firefox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы заставить  clip-path работать в Firefox, необходимо указывать значения точек в полигоне или в патче не в процентах, а в пикселях или дробными цифрами не более "1.0" то есть от "0.01" до "1.0"
При выборе последнего (дробного) варианта, необходимо указывать режим `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >

  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-ff" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points="0.2, 0.1 0.7,0.2 1,1 0,1.8"></polygon>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="http://placeimg.com/300/400/any" clip-path="url(#clip-ff)" width="400" height="400"> </image>
</svg>
```

Работает в IE11, FF, Chrome, Opera