# Как создать такие скошенные углы

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

Как создать такие скошенные углы  при помощи svg clipPath?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский я не согласен, что это дубликат с указанной ссылкой. По форме да, фигура повторяется, но она реализована совершенно другим способом, чем в указанном источнике. Здесь решение  - SVG, в источнике несколько решений на CSS и canvas.  Используя подобную практику - метить дубликатами одинаковые фигуры в разных вопросах, можно дойти до абсурда.- метить дубликатами вопросы, где встречаются : чекбоксы, радиокнопки, выпадающие меню, кнопки со скошенными углами, треугольники, круги. Мне кажется, что надо всё-таки смотреть на техн. решение, а не на внешнее сходство.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Как заставить работать clip-path в Firefox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/659502/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-clip-path-%D0%B2-firefox/659522#659522) - всё точно также, только координаты полигона другие.
Начало - левый, верхний угол - `0,0`
 Далее правый верхний угол - `1,0`
Верт. вниз  --`1,0.1`
Скос до середины - `0.5, 0.2`
Скос от середины - `0,0.1`

```
 <polygon points="0,0  1,0  1,0.1  0.5, 0.2 0,0.1"></polygon>
```

```html
 <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="800" height="200" viewBox="0 0 800 200" >

  <defs>
<clipPath id="clip-ff" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
  <polygon points="0,0  1,0  1,0.1  0.5, 0.2 0,0.1"></polygon>
</clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="http://placeimg.com/800/800/any" clip-path="url(#clip-ff)" width="800" height="800"> </image>
</svg>
```